# What are possible drop from Shadow Orbs (In Terraria)

Tags: terraria

I have found a musket but I don't really know what it can drop, I'm curious, thanks for the feed-back

Comment: Move to close. Lacks basic research. OP, [please consult the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb). Answers not found there can definitely be sought here, as long as they can be answered (and not just discussed).

Comment: @MathieuK., low research is a valid reason to downvote, but not a valid close reason.

Answer (score 6):

From a [very quick search](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb), you can obtain a [Musket](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Musket) and 100 [Musket Balls](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Musket_Ball), a [Shadow Orb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb_(item)), a [Vilethorn](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vilethorn), a [Ball O' Hurt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ball_O%27_Hurt), or a [Band of Starpower](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Band_of_Starpower), all with the same chance.

The very first Shadow Orb broken in a world will always drop a Musket and Musket Balls.